Livepatch problem
Under the Livepatch icon, I keep receiving the following message:
Livepatch is on 
An error occured when checking for Livepatch updates

The command /snap/bin/canonical-livepatch status provided the following output:
last check: 12 minutes ago
kernel: 5.15.0-116.126-generic
server check-in: failed: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/7b9a1f4d8c6e3a2b9c4d7f8e1a2b3c6d/updates" failed
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 5.15 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 5.15.0-116.126-generic
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: 7b9a1f4d8c6e3a2b9c4d7f8e1a2b3c6d[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Important: This is not a copy of Why does LivePatch fail this morning after normal updates gave me new kernel? , because https://status.snapcraft.io/ shows that all components are operational, and sudo snap refresh says that all packages are up to date.
